# How to Change order of error dispaly in custom user registration fileds in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have customized new user registration form using child theme concept.
For this I override the form-login.php file.

> wp-content/pluings/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php

My new from is looks like this
[image]

Code for Custom registration Filed

```
<form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <p class="form-row form-row-first">
                <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
                </p>

                <p class="form-row form-row-last">
                <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
                </p>

                <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_dob"><?php _e( 'Date of Birth', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="reg_customer_dob" id="reg_customer_dob"  />
                </p>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

                <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_billing_email_cnfrm"><?php _e( 'Please Confirm Email Address ', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_email_cnfrm" id="reg_billing_email_cnfrm"  />
                </p>

                <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
                </p>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="confirm_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="user_password_again" id="confirm_password" autocomplete="confirm-password" />
                </p>

                <?php else : ?>

                <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Mobile', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone"  />
                </p>

                <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>
```

I am validating the fields like this -

```
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
           $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
           $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_mobile_number_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Mobile number is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) && empty( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Date of Birth is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_password_again'] ) && empty( $_POST['user_password_again'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Confirm Password is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( $_POST['user_password_again']  != $_POST['password']  ) {
        //$_POST['password'] Default password filed
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Password not match!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Confirm Email is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm']  != $_POST['email']  ) {
        //$_POST['eamil'] Default eamil filed
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Email not match!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
 

       return $validation_errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );
```

In validation process, form is validating & working correct but display error message in the wrong order .(Image attached for better clarity of issue)

[image]

At present it displaying the error in the following order

1. Email
2. Password
3. Firstname
4. Lastname
5. Mobile number
6. Date of birth
7. Confirm Password
8. Confirm Email

But it should be in Following order -

1. Firstname
2. Last Name
3. Date of birth
4. Email
5. Confirm Email
6. Password
7. Confirm Password
8. Mobile no.

**Can any one please Help me to change the order of error message**

**Update**

Changing the orders of IF block in validation is not fixing the issue . I have already tried this.

Comment: First of all, you're using the wrong hook `woocommerce_register_post` returns `$username`. However, if you use the correct hook, it will show the error messages (depending on which hook you use) before or after the default email - password error messages. So you would have to delete/rebuild the validation for the existing fields to match the order of displaying the error messages. Your adjustments to the template file also contain some mistakes, for example, you use the `reg_` prefix interchangeably. In short, what you ask is certainly possible, but requires an extensive answer

Comment: Hi 7uc1f3r.Thanks for reply. Can you please suggest me which should i use to change the order OR I should use JS based validation.Your suggestion will be very helpful to me.

Comment: The following [link](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-user-functions.php#L41-L80) points to the file where the validation is performed. On line 78 you see your current hook, on line 80 the hook you should/could use. Only you will see on line 43, 47.. etc.. that **return is used**. So these error messages are executed before your hook is executed. Since there is no possibility to change this via a hook you will have to rewrite the `wc_create_new_customer()` function to meet your question

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r for your help. I am checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) && empty( $_POST['reg_customer_dob'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Date of Birth is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Confirm Email is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( $_POST['billing_email_cnfrm'] != $_POST['email']  ) {
        //$_POST['eamil'] Default eamil filed
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Email not match!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['user_password_again'] ) && empty( $_POST['user_password_again'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Confirm Password is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( $_POST['user_password_again'] != $_POST['password']  ) {
        //$_POST['password'] Default password filed
        $validation_errors->add( 'reg_customer_dob_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Password not match!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_mobile_number_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Mobile number is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    
    return $validation_errors;

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks bhautik for reply. I have already tried this approach (changing of validation orders of if block) before asking the question for changing the order but my bad luck it is not working.